# Not able to write file with csv extention into AWS S3 from pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write a file amazon S3 from dataframe .

I am unable to get file in csv format in S3.

**My code**

```
import s3fs
bytes_to_write = data_upload.to_csv(index=False).encode()
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='secret_key',secret='secret_secret')
with fs.open('cotydata/datadump'+'_'+(date.today()).strftime("%Y%m%d").csv, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

**My expected output**

datadump_20190401.csv
datadump_20190402.csv

How can this  be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parts of the filename have to be quoted correctly. Also datetime needs to be used correctly:

```
import s3fs
bytes_to_write = data_upload.to_csv(index=False).encode()
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='secret_key',secret='secret_secret')
with fs.open('cotydata/datadump_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes_to_write)
```